# How to assign value to a variable when the value contain a $ character in it

Tags: shell-script, password, ksh, variable

My objective: Automate scp from one server to another taking inputs from user
Challenge: I can not setup ssh authorized host equivalence between the servers because one user having access to target will also get access to source server So, I need to setup legacy method of providing password when prompted and then do scp.

Here is my code

```
L_SRC_SID=source
L_SID=target
MOUNT_POINT=app07
SERVICE_PASS=some$value
APP_SERVER_1=hostname
SRC_MOUNT_POINT=app01

#And now transfer the file over
/usr/bin/expect -c "
   set timeout 1
   cd /$MOUNT_POINT/$L_SID/apps
   spawn scp -pr * apps@$APP_SERVER_1:/$SRC_MOUNT_POINT/$L_SRC_SID/apps .
   expect yes/no { send yes\r ; exp_continue }
   expect password: { send $SERVICE_PASS\r }
   expect 100%
   sleep 1
   exit
"

exit
```

Challenges:
1. I am unable to assign some$value value to variable SERVICE_PASS
2. How to make the expect send script work using such a variable that has $ character in the password. It is failing with the below error.

```
password: can't read "value": no such variable
```

Any help is appreciated

I have changed the code as per suggestions, but still getting the same error

```
L_SRC_SID=source
L_SID=target
MOUNT_POINT=app07
SERVICE_PASS='some$value'
APP_SERVER_1=hostname
SRC_MOUNT_POINT=app01

#And now transfer the file over
/usr/bin/expect -c "
   set timeout 1
   cd /$MOUNT_POINT/$L_SID/apps
   spawn scp -pr * apps@$APP_SERVER_1:/$SRC_MOUNT_POINT/$L_SRC_SID/apps .
   expect yes/no { send yes\r ; exp_continue }
   expect password: { send $SERVICE_PASS\r }
   expect 100%
   sleep 1
   exit
"

exit
```

Here is the complete error.

```
password: can't read "value": no such variable
    while executing
"send some$value\r "
    invoked from within
"expect password: { send some$value\r }"
```

Comment: What will stop the users just looking at your script and seeing what the password is? There are far, far, more secure ways of copying a file under program control than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using double quotes for the expect script body, you have to deal with **both** shell variable expansion and expect (i.e. Tcl) variable expansion. When expect is running, the shell variable has been expanded, so expect sees this:

```
expect password: { send some$value\r }
```

So now, you need to deal with Tcl variables.

You *could* add more quoting:

```
/usr/bin/expect -c "
    ...
    expect password: { send {$SERVICE_PASS}; send \r }
```

But that's not necessary:
I would put the expect script in single quotes, and pass the shell parameters through the environment. That way, each variable will only be substituted once: either in the shell or in expect, and you won't get any surprises.

```
export L_SRC_SID L_SID MOUNT_POINT SERVICE_PASS APP_SERVER_1 SRC_MOUNT_POINT

/usr/bin/expect -c '  # <- single quote
    set timeout -1
    cd /$env(MOUNT_POINT)/$env(L_SID)/apps
    spawn scp -pr * apps@$env(APP_SERVER_1):/$env(SRC_MOUNT_POINT)/$env(L_SRC_SID)/apps .
    expect {
        yes/no    { send yes\r ; exp_continue }
        password: { send $env(SERVICE_PASS)\r }
    }
    expect eof
'
```

In general, use of `sleep` in expect means you either have the wrong timeout or you're expecting the wrong thing. I changed both.

Comment: This works. Excellent solution. Thank you Glenn for the response.

Answer (score 3):

For this situation you will want to surround your value in single quotes:

```
'some$value'
```

Double quotes `""` suppress filename expansion but not variable expansion.

```
$ value="some$value"
$ echo $value
 some
```

Single quotes `''` suppress both filename and variable expansion.

```
$ value='some$value'
$ echo $value
 some$value
```

Back ticks ``` `` ``` allow variable Expansion

```
$ value=`some$value`
$ echo $value`

$
```

So, to suppress expansions of characters such as `$`, `!`, `"`, and `/`  use single quotes!

Comment: Please don't recommend backticks. They have long been supplanted by the `$(...)` construct.

Comment: Nice answer, formatting is a bit messed up tho

Comment: Thank you. Single quote working fine to retain the variable value with $ character. But my expect portion is still throwing the same error. 

    password: can't read "value": no such variable

Comment: L_SRC_SID=source
    L_SID=target
    MOUNT_POINT=app07
    SERVICE_PASS='some$value'
    APP_SERVER_1=hostname
    SRC_MOUNT_POINT=app01

    #And now transfer the file over
    /usr/bin/expect -c "
       set timeout 1
       cd /$MOUNT_POINT/$L_SID/apps
       spawn scp -pr * 
    apps@$APP_SERVER_1:/$SRC_MOUNT_POINT/$L_SRC_SID/apps .
       expect yes/no { send yes\r ; exp_continue }
       expect password: { send $SERVICE_PASS\r }
       expect 100%
       sleep 1
       exit
    "

    exit

Comment: single quote at the expect portion isn't working still. Could you please check and tell me?

Comment: I think it may be possible that you send the correct password with this: `expect password: { send $SERVICE_PASS\r }` But whatever receives the password might see `some$value\r` and try to reference `$value` in it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `'strong quotes'`; special characters such as `$`, `!`, `"`, and `\` have no meaning within them.